# Roteirização de html com iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net

Eu tenho uma aplicação que serve com um HELP para o sistema, ou seja o usuário clica no ponto de interrogação e instataneamente abre uma nova aba com esse HELP direto na página equivalente, porém como esse tem seus caminhos tratados com `iframe/JavaScript` o caminho fica incompleto e assim, abre apenas a página inicial do HELP e, não na página específica.

Como eu passo um caminho para um `href`que está sendo tratado por `JavaScript` onde ele retorna uma `div` com `iframe`?

Exemplo (JS):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function clickLink(link){
    document.getElementById("iframeTeste").src =  link;
}
</script>
```

Exemplo (Html):

```
<li>
    <a href="#" onclick="clickLink('CaixaSeparacao.html')">Caixa Separação</a>
</li>


<div id="teste" >
    <iframe id="iframeTeste" style="position: absolute; border: 0;    margin-top: 72px;    width: 100%;    height: 80%;    z-index:-1;">
    </iframe>
</div>
```

Aqui a chamada do HELP que deveria abrir na página específica no `.NET`:

```
<div class="imagem">
    <a href="../PCI.HELP/index.html" target="_blank">
        <img src="../PCI.HELP/helpmenor.png"/>
    </a>
</div>
```